# Get latest post link on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have that site : http://ougk.gr and I want on the navigation to have a link which points to the latest post of a specific category (full post with comments etc). How can I achieve that?

Comment: have you seen wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. This one uses [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), and prints a basic link:

```
<nav>

    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'category' => CAT_ID );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">Latest Post</a>';
        }
    ?>

    // .. other menu code ..

</nav>
```

Where `CAT_ID` is the id of the targeted category. For your situation the simple answer is to insert the link code just after the opening nav tag, as above.

To place the link somewhere else in the nav, you'll have to dive into some of the other functions called in the code you pasted. It might be a good idea to get your hands dirty..

Comment: oh thank you so much dude! how can i give it a name? for example "Latest Post"

Comment: @hambos22 "name" as in the link text? or simply a description of what you're about to click on?

Comment: name as the link text,this is the code of the navigation part `<nav> <?php if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) { wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-nav' , 'fallback_cb' => 'default_main_nav' , 'container' => '' , 'menu_id' => 'main-nav' , 'menu_class' => 'main-nav')); } else { default_main_nav(); } ?> <!--/main-nav --> </nav>` How can i add the latest post link on the nav?

Comment: @hambos22 see my edit. if this works for you please checkmark

Comment: For anyone wanting just a simple way to get the latest post's permalink, this works well: `$latest_post = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) ); $latest_post_url = get_permalink( $latest_post[0]['ID'] );`

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
        'numberposts' => '1', 
    );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):

    $post_id        = $recent['ID'];
    $post_url       = get_permalink($recent['ID']);
    $post_title     = $recent['post_title'];
    $post_content   = $recent['post_content'];
    $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']);

    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I wanted to use this function as a Shortcode in WordPress so I followed this easy to follow guide on creating your own: https://torquemag.io/2017/06/custom-shortcode/ Needed to just wrap the above in a function and then return the result. Able to then use a simple Shortcode like [getLatestPostTitleAndLink].

Answer (score 0):

You need ot get the title and perma link

```
<?php
// retrieve one post with an ID of 5
query_posts( 'cat=X&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC' );

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       echo "<a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>";
       the_title();
       echo "</a>";
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: ok this is the code of the navigation part `<nav>
    <?php if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
     wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-nav' , 'fallback_cb' => 'default_main_nav' , 'container'  => '' , 'menu_id' => 'main-nav' , 'menu_class' => 'main-nav'));
    } else {
     default_main_nav();
    } ?>
    <!--/main-nav -->
   </nav>`

How can i add the latest post link on the nav?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of always showing the latest post from a category. Also please correct syntax error in your echo line.